# Probability Mass Functions

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question regarding probability mass functions.

I have been learning about joint p.m.fs and how to find the marginal p.m.fs from the joint p.m.fs, however I'm completely unsure how to tackle this problem below. Any help being pointed in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Given the table below and the fact that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables, how would I go about finding P($X_1$+$X_2$$\le$$1$ | $X_1$=$0$)?

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{P($X_i$=0)} & \text{P($X_i$=1)}& \text{P($X_i$=2)} & \text{$i$=1,2}\\ \hline
\text{$X_1$} & p & 3p & 1-4p &(0<p<1/4) \\ \hline
\text{$X_2$} & p & p^2 & 1-p-p^2 & (0<p<1/2)\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(X_1+X_2 \leq 1 \mid X_1=0) &= \frac{P(\{X_1+X_2 \leq 1\} \cap \{X_1=0\})}{P(X_1=0)}\\
&=\frac{P(X_2 \leq 1)}{P(X_1=0)}
\end{align}

Can you follow from here?

Edit:

There is an error in the above expression because $\{X_1+X_2 \leq 1\} \cap \{X_1=0\}$ is equal to $\{X_2 \leq 1\} \cap \{X_1=0\}$ and not just $\{X_2 \leq 1\}$. The correct expression would be

\begin{align}
P(X_1+X_2 \leq 1 \mid X_1=0)&= \frac{P(\{X_1+X_2 \leq 1\} \cap \{X_1=0\})}{P(X_1=0)}\\
&=\frac{P(\{X_2 \leq 1\} \cap \{X_1=0\})}{P(X_1=0)}\\
&=\frac{P(X_2 \leq 1)P(X_1=0)}{P(X_1=0)}\\
&= P(X_2 \leq 1)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. Would it then become ${p+p^2\over p}$=1+p ? 

I'm unsure where to go from there with regards to the information given in the last column. Do I leave the answer as is or do I need to use the intervals for p?

Comment: You are right! The last column is telling you the values of $p$ that are valid and in that sense you should specify in the answer that the valid interval for $p$ is the smallest one, this because is the intersection of the intervals for $X_1$ and $X_2$. Those are the valid intervals for $p$ because, for example, for $X_1$, $p=1/2$ would give us a negative probability for $X_1=2$.

Comment: Thank you! You've explained it so well. Would the same idea apply to the means and variances. For example, for E($X_1$-$X_2$), would I work it out as:

E($X_1$-$X_2$)=E($X_1$)-E($X_2$)=(2-5p)-(2-2p-$p^2$)=$p^2$-3p with $0<p<1/4$  ?

Comment: You are again right! ;)

Comment: "Would it then become $...=1+p$?" Hmmm, probabilities greater than $1$?

Comment: Oh. I hadn't thought about that. What other way could I tackle this question?

Comment: I made an edit. I apologize. Thanks @stef for pointing me out the error.

Comment: @CarlosMendoza Now it is correct I think.